# How to get focused wind in a simulation? Like a fan or leaf blower

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have seen several tutorials on using wind and cloth. Very cool and very educational. But one thing that I can't make sense of. Wind doesn't appear to be possible to focus a stream of wind like what you would get out of a fan or leaf blower.

For example, in these two images, you can see that I am using a wind source with a tube falloff. But the tube means nothing. Even when the cloth is nowhere near the tube, it acts exactly like it does when it is right in front of the tube.

Pointing at the cloth

[image: Pointing at the cloth]

Pointing away from the cloth

[image: Pointing away from the cloth]

The cloth is flowing in the correct direction based on the wind in both images, but how can I make the wind a stream or jet of air rather than acting like a plane the entire time?

I have tried using a point and a cone and those don't work either. I have tried changing the shape of the wind force itself using a point, line and plane and I cannot see the difference on the output.

The wind seems like it is acting more as a global wind direction rather than the null wind object being the source of the wind.

Any suggestions to help me understand how wind should work and how to make a specific object the source of the wind would be fantastic.

---

james_1 gave the answer I needed below but I wanted to show the updated settings. I had the Radial set to ZERO which appears to me infinity. This number seems a little confusing because the higher the number the lower the radius of the wind tube. For my example, I found that 8 worked the way I was expecting. Here are the updated images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this comes up on search engines and helps others looking for the same info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to include a screenshot of your falloff settings. Radial Power should not be zero.   Here is an example using Rigid Body physics with a tube-style wind with non-zero Radial falloff.

[image]

This example: [image]